# Создать новый перевернутый массив с измененными значениями в одной колонке и сохранением исходного

Tags: java

Есть двумерный строковый массив, необходимо создать новый превернутый (с конца) и изменить в последней колонке числа.
Пробовал такой код:

```
String[x][y] ar - заполненный массив (см. ниже)

int str = ar.lenght; // количество строк в массиве
int col = ar[0].length; // количество столбцов
String[][] result = new String[str][col]; // новый массив для результатов
for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
{
  result[i] = ar[str - 1 - i]; // переворачивает массив
  result[i][col-1] = const - Integer.parseInt(ar[str - 1 - i][col-1]) + ""; // *
}
```

если в коде отсутствует строка *, то создается перевернутый массив, а исходный остается как был.
Но если добавить строку *, чтобы изменить числа в последней колонке массива, то в исходном массиве (ar) также изменяются значения в последней колонке.
Пробовал разные вариции, но результат тот же.
Чего не хватает?
Спасибо.

> что именно вы переворачиваете

Поясню.
Перевернуть - в новом массиве первой строкой должна быть послендяя из исходного, второй - предпоследняя и т.д.

> И что значит в последнем столбце поменять числа?

последняя колонка исходного массива содержит числа (в текстовом формате, поскольку в других колонках есть текст). Поэтому в коде использую преобразование из текста в целое число, делаю вычисления (из Константы отнимаю число содержащееся в колонке) и полученное значение преобразую в строковое, которым и пытаюсь заменить исходное в строке новго массива.
Для наглядности:

```
Исходный массив: String[3][4] ar = 
[a1, b1, c1, "2"]
[a2, b2, c2, "7"]
[a3, b3, c3, "4"]

const = 10

Новый массив:
[a3, b3, c3, "6"]
[a2, b2, c2, "3"]
[a1, b1, c1, "8"]
```

---

> String[x][y] ar - заполненный массив что это и откуда у тебя взялись x и y?

так указал исходный массив, считайте, что он заполнен данными приведенными в тексте (подправил текст).

> int str = ar.lenght;

определяю количество строк исходного массива, а а следующей строкой, количество колонок для того, чтобы содать новый такого же размера.

---

> присвоение ссылок ссылкам. ... Вам нужно в двойном цикле переприсваивать все элементы.

Это понимаю - была такая мысль, но попробовал следующий код с созданием нового ссылочного объекта для замены в массиве, но результат тот же:

```
for (int i = str - 1; i >= 0; )
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < str; j++)
        {
            result[j] = ar[i];
            result[j][col-1] = new String(const - Integer.parseInt(ar[i][col-1]) + "");
            i--;
        }
    }
```

что делаю не так, пока не доходит...

---

> 1 ответ Andrew Bystrovвсе

Благодарю. На экран результат выводится верный, но отладчик также показывает измененную последнную колонку в исходном массиве.

Видимо мой код тоже тогда работоспособен. Его не проверял на вывод результатов. Доверился инфе которую показал отладчик, а он, показывает измененный исходный массив...

Вопрос закрываю.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что именно вы переворачиваете. Вы строки в массиве меняете между собой? Или в каждую строку нужно инвертировать? И что значит в последнем столбце поменять числа? О каких числах вы говорите, если у вас массив `String`?

Comment: `String[x][y] ar - заполненный массив` что это и откуда у тебя взялись x и y?

Comment: `int str = ar.lenght;` тут совершенно непонятно что ты делаешь

Comment: `int col = ar[0].length;` и тут тоже самое, дальше нет смысла смотреть.

Comment: Вероятно проблема в том, что вот эта строка `result[i] = ar[str - 1 - i];` это не копирование строк из массива `ar` в `result`. А присвоение ссылок ссылкам. В итоге они у вас указывают на одни и те же данные. Вам нужно в двойном цикле переприсваивать все элементы.

Comment: @tron78 Вот [тут](https://sky.pro/media/massivy-java/) подробное описание по массивам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не изменялись значения в исходном массиве, нужно копировать значения его строк.  Для этого можно использовать методы [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) или [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), *в крайнем случае* ещё один цикл по колонкам:

```java
public static String[][] reverseAndChange(String[][] arr, int c) {
    int n = arr.length;
    int m = arr[0].length;
    String[][] res = new String[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        //res[i] = Arrays.copyOf(arr[n - 1 - i], m);
        //System.arraycopy(arr[n - 1 - i], 0, res[i], 0, m);
        for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {
            res[i][j] = arr[n - 1 - i][j];
        }
        res[i][m - 1] = String.valueOf(c - Integer.parseInt(arr[i][m - 1]));
    }
    return res;
}
```

Тест:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] arr = {
            {"a1", "b1", "c1", "2"},
            {"a2", "b2", "c2", "7"},
            {"a3", "b3", "c3", "4"}
    };

    String[][] updated = reverseAndChange(arr, 10);
    System.out.println("Input: ");
    out(arr);
    System.out.println("Result: ");
    out(updated);
}

private static void out(String[][] arr) {
    for (String[] row : arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Input: 
[a1, b1, c1, 2]
[a2, b2, c2, 7]
[a3, b3, c3, 4]
Result: 
[a3, b3, c3, 6]
[a2, b2, c2, 3]
[a1, b1, c1, 8]
```

Comment: Я не хотел пользоваться методами Arrays или другими. Только простой код.

Comment: Простой код - это лишний цикл, но в принципе `System.arraycopy` достаточно приемлемое решение, и в начальном вопросе не указано такое ограничение.

Comment: _Видимо мой код тоже тогда работоспособен. Его не проверял на вывод результатов. Доверился инфе которую показал отладчик, а он, показывает измененный исходный массив_  И ваш код, и код в [принятом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1492711/386633) **будет изменять** содержимое исходного массива, в отличие от приведённого в моём ответе.

Comment: Возможно, не могу спорить, буду смотреть... поскольку программирую по необходимости попутно разбираясь и решая проблемы...

Comment: Тут не с чем особо спорить :)

Comment: В люлом случае спасибо. Учитывая что описанная проблема решилась локально, но глобально осталась, как отписал в отмеченном ответе, посмотрю ваше решение, поэкспериментирую...

Comment: У меня Ваш код посчитался неверно :) В первой строке результирующего массива получил: [a3, b3, c3, 8] - последняя цифра должна быть "6". Поищу, что не так...

Comment: Да . Ваше решение безупречно. Все работает как надо. А оказалось все просто - перечитать ячейки в строках и оставить пустой последнюю колонку, чтобы заполнить нужными данными,  а не заменить. Только в приведенном поде нужно подредактировать строку: res[i][m - 1] = String.valueOf(c - Integer.parseInt(arr[n - 1 - i][m - 1]));

Answer (score -2):

```java
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arr = new String[][]{
                {"a1", "b1", "c1", "2"},
                {"a2", "b2", "c2", "7"},
                {"a3", "b3", "c3", "4"}
        };
        System.out.println("Input: ");
        out(arr);

        int c = 10;
        int n = arr.length;
        int m = arr[0].length;
        String[][] res = new String[n][m];
        
        // суть
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            res[i] = arr[n - i - 1];
            String prevValue = res[i][m - 1];
            res[i][m - 1] = String.valueOf(c - Integer.parseInt(prevValue));
        }

        System.out.println("Result: ");
        out(res);
    }

    private static void out(String[][] a) {
        for (String[] strings : a) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема вернулась - когда реализовал код в виде класса в который передаю исходный массив, то в вызывающем классе исходный массив меняется.